# What does 降土 mean?

Tags: meaning

It's a conversation from video game, people live in a flying saucer-like city (Shevat).

Context - これは、プラントシェルだよ。このなかでシェバトで必要な
野菜やら果物やらを育ててるのさ。今は大切な降土期だから、
関係者いがい立ち入り禁止さ。人間は、バイ菌のかたまりだからね。

土 is soil, earth.

降 is descend, fall.

So maybe 降土 means something like "planting"?

Comment: The word 土降る means 'to rain dust'; maybe it's important for a flying city to have dust-rain because there's no natural soil, and such seasons exist in this game world where this commonly occurs...

Comment: But it's not 土降, it's 降土, are they mean the same? And how it relates to this part - "...関係者いがい立ち入り禁止さ。人間は、バイ菌のかたまりだからね。" - "...Only the staff members are allowed to go in. Since humans are a mass of germs." ?

Comment: I'd assume that 土降る means the same as 降土 in the same way that 雨が降る means roughly the same as 降雨..  & I suppose it has something to do with not wanting to contaminate the soil where they grow crops or something. It's just a guess; as far as I'm aware 降土期 is something made up for this game in particular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

降土 is not a word ordinary people use. It's a made-up word, but it can instantly be understood as the 土 version of 降雨 ("rainfall") or 降雪 ("snowfall"). Thus "soilfall" or something like that.